# ColdFusion loop nested pound sign issue

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-9

I am trying to evaluate two dynamically assigned variables; then attempting to assign a dynamic variable based on the outcome.
I have much longer code where this works, but I am trying to consolidate.

Here is what I have for the consolidated code:

```
<cfloop list="dog,cat,pig,horse" index="i">      
    <cfif (#trim([i]_FMCTotal)# /2) GT #trim([i]_FMC)#>
        <cfset #i#colorCode = 'red'>
    <cfelseif (#trim([i]_FMCTotal)# /1.5) GT #trim([i]_FMC)#>
        <cfset #i#colorCode = 'yellow'>
    <cfelse>
        <cfset #i#colorCode = 'green'>
    </cfif>  
</cfloop>
```

Comment: Phil's answer looks the best. I just wanted to point out that there is a very specific use of pound signs in CF and that is for string interpolation. That is when you have a string and want a variable or expression stuffed in the middle. There are two cases where this is used. First, when making a string you can do this for example  <cfset phrase = "the dog is #size# and #color#" />. The other is when generating output so for example <cfoutput>My brother just said #phrase# to my mom</cfoutput>. Actually including pound signs in other situations may not generate an error but serve no purpose.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Not much of the code you have posted would get through the parser as you have a few invalid CFML constructs such as `[i]_FMCTotal` which is not a valid variable name. Also your use of the hashes is not required within the conditional statements, the hashes are used for output.

To answer the question there is `evaluate()` but a far more readable, secure and maintainable solution would be to leverage a struct for the colour codes.

```
<cfset colorCodes = {}>
<!--- presuming ..._FMCTotal and .._FMC are reworked as structs also --->
<cfloop list="dog,cat,pig,horse" index="i">      
    <cfif (FMCTotal[i] /2) GT trim(FMC[i])>
        <cfset colorCode[i] = 'red'>
    <cfelseif (trim(FMCTotal[i] /1.5) GT trim(FMC[i])>
        <cfset colorCode[i] = 'yellow'>
    <cfelse>
        <cfset colorCode[i] = 'green'>
    </cfif>  
</cfloop>
```

The result of this would be a data structure from which you can easily access any of the items value in subsequent code

```
{ // possible result
    'pig': 'green'
  , 'cat': 'yellow'
  , 'dog': 'red'
  , 'horse': 'green'
}

colorCode['dog'] // => 'red'
```

If you don't have access to rework the _FMC variables you could evaluate those `evaluate('#i#_FMCTotal')` but it would be far cleaner to use a collection for these also as in my example.

Comment: Thanks Phil and Mark and Dan. I just read Bamboozled by Pound Sign Decisions (http://www.coldfusionmuse.com/index.cfm/2011/2/10/when.do.i.use.pound.signs). I really appreciate the input.

Comment: Phil, your code worked. I just needed to add a ")" at the end of the cfelseif:  <cfelseif (trim(FMCTotal[i] /1.5) GT trim(FMC[i]))>. Thank you guys very much...

Answer (score 1):

Phil's right - your syntax is not correct. If what you are trying to do with

is see if the variable pig_FmcTotal divided by 2 is greater than pig_FMC, then you should be doing something like:

```
<cfif val(variables[i & '_FMCTotal']) / 2 gt val(variables[i & '_FMC'])>
```

I'm assuming that _FMC is actually a string here but if it was a variable you would remove the single quotes above. Use bracket notation and concatenate the key name within the bracket. There are other ways to do this (evaluate for example).

When it comes to setting it's the same routine:

```
<cfset variables[i & colorscheme] = 'green'/>
```

Good luck.